# Is it possible to remove a flag from a question or comment?

Tags: support, moderators, flagging

Ok so it looks like I may have been hasty in flagging an answer yesterday, as it seemed to me to be more mischievous than helpful. However it has since been clarified and now appears to make sense. Is there a way to remove the flag I raised against it to save moderator's time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to remove flags you've raised, only for a moderator to action them.